# When $C_v=\left.\frac {\delta Q} {dT}\right|_v=\left.\frac {\partial E} {\partial T}\right|_v$?

Tags: thermodynamics, magnetic-fields

The definition of specific heat at constant volume is $C_v=\left.\frac {\delta Q} {dT}\right|_v$  but sometimes I find this expression instead: $C_v=\left.\frac {\partial E} {\partial T}\right|_v$ . I guess that the reason why these two expression are both used is that they are equivalent, however I don't know how to demonstrate it.

I tried to demonstrate the equivalence by myself but I was able to do it only assuming $\delta W=-PdV$ indeed in this case: $dE=\delta Q +\delta W=\delta Q - PdV \rightarrow \left.dE\right|_v=\delta Q$ so it follow
$C_v=\left.\frac {\delta Q} {dT}\right|_v=\left.\frac {\partial E} {\partial T}\right|_v$ .

However, when I don't assume $\delta W=-PdV$ it becomes impossible for me to show that $C_v=\left.\frac {\delta Q} {dT}\right|_v=\left.\frac {\partial E} {\partial T}\right|_v$. Consider for example the case of a paramagnetic materials, since it can be magnetized the expression for the work should be $\delta W=-PdV+BdM$ where $M$ is the magnetization and $B$ is the magnetic field.
Even in this case i think the expression $C_v=\left.\frac {\partial E} {\partial T}\right|_v$ is valid. Why?

Note: in the last example I think that the independent variables are $V$ and $T$ while the number of particle and the magnetic field are taken constant and that $M=M(V,T)$

Comment: That is the definition of Cv.

Comment: It is not clear where you get the last relation. If both $V$ and $M$ are present, you should specify what else is taken constant when partial derivatives are evaluated.

Comment: @GiorgioP thank you for the observation. I tried to edit the question to make it clear. About the $\delta W=-PdV+BdM$: i think the magnetic field is taken constant and also the number of particles while $M=M(V,T)$

Comment: Then, in our last case, you should be working with a $C_{v,B}= \left.\frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{T}}\right|_{v,B}$. The independent variables are $V$, $T$, and $B$.

Comment: However, I do not see why the introduction of an additional variable should solve your starting problem.

Comment: @GiorgioP the problem is that the two definitions of specific heat that I wrote are different in this case

Comment: If there is an additional variable, why should you get the same expression?

Comment: @GiorgioP I don't think i0m understanding your point,  $C_v=\frac {\delta Q} {dT}|_v$ should be the formal definition of $C_v$. I'm trying to show that this is equivalent to  $\frac {\partial E} {\partial T}|_v$. If the equivalence is true then when i change the variables both $\delta Q$ and $dE$ should change. Have you seen the edit to the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138601/discussion-between-simobartz-and-giorgiop).

Answer (score 2):

$\delta Q$ is a non-exact differential form.
According to the First Law of Thermodynamics
$$\delta Q=dU+\delta W$$
Where $\delta W$ is the work differential form and $dU$ is the differential of the internal, which is an exact differential form. For mechanical work only $\delta W=pdV$.

Let's consider a $pVT$ system. To define specific heat at constant volume, consider $(T,V)$ as independent variables, then the heat differential form is

$$\delta Q=\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_TdV+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_VdT}_{dU}+p(T,V)dV$$
Specific heat at constant volume $C_v$ is defined as the *component along $dT$* of the differential form $\delta Q^1$, i.e.
$$C_v=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V \tag{A}$$

To emphasize the definition, writing heat differential form more generally as
$$\delta Q=f(T,V)dT+g(T,V)dV$$

Specific heat at constant volume is *defined* as the function $f(T,V)$. As you can see above, this coefficient is equal to $(A)$.

---

$^1$<sub>This is the reason why the other variable is $V$ and not $p$, so that the volume is fixed when differentiating with respect to T.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, i found this answer useful but unfortunately it seems that you are also assuming $\delta W=-PdV$. My question is about when this is not true. I edited the question to make it clear, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

The formal definition of the specific heat at constant volume is

$$c_{v}=\biggl (\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}\biggr )_v$$

Your last expression does not show that the partial derivative is at constant volume.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You formal definition of specific heat is different from the one i'm accustomed to. I edited the question to make it clear. Can you give me some extra details?

Comment: $c_v$ is a thermodynamic property and, as such, it is defined in terms of another thermodynamic property, $du$. A quantity of heat, $\delta q$ is not a thermodynamic property. The equation $\delta q=c_{v}dT$ calculates the amount of heat that causes a change in temperature at constant volume and is derived by applying the formal definition of $c_v$ along with the first law for a closed system as you already know.  But it is not the definition of $c_v$.